# How to invoke a method received as parameter inside an object literal

Tags: javascript

I run this code without any errors:

```
(function(a, b){
return a.foo = {
    call: function(name, args) {
        this.myFunction.call(null, args)
    },
    myFunction: function(args) {
        console.log("myFunction has been called!");
        console.log(args);
    }
}

})(window, document);

foo.call('myFunction', ['arg1', 'arg2']);
```

However, if I use `this.name.call(null, args)` instead of `this.myFunction.call(null, args)` like this:

```
(function(a, b){
return a.foo = {
    call: function(name, args) {
        this.name.call(null, args)
    },
    myFunction: function(args) {
        console.log("myFunction has been called!");
        console.log(args);
    }
}

})(window, document);

foo.call('myFunction', ['arg1', 'arg2']);
```

I get the `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined` error.

How can I invoke a function from a string parameter?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the attribute using brackets: `this[name].call(null, args)`

That way you're accesing the attributes of object `foo`

```js
(function(a, b){
return a.foo = {
    call: function(name, args) {
        this[name].call(null, args)
    },
    myFunction: function(args) {
        console.log("myFunction has been called!");
        console.log(args);
    }
}

})(window, document);

foo.call('myFunction', ['arg1', 'arg2']);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: That's precisely it. Thks a lot!

Comment: If I add another method like myFunction2: function() {console.log("myFunction2 has been called!")} how can I call it from inside the myFunction method? Tried with this.myFunction2() and this[myFunction2] without success.